# Selecting a column with period in the column name SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server, historian

I am linked to a Proficy Historian that allows periods in the column names.  Because the data is stored in a non DBMS format I can not use `openquery` to get the data because there is no set schema to the tables.  So I must use four part name syntax to get the data.  This example works:

```
SELECT * FROM iHist...[SELECT * FROM ihTrend]
```

but this fails with *Incorrect syntax near '.'.*

```
SELECT * FROM iHist...[SELECT [SERVER.pid_astatus[07][0].F_CV.Value] FROM ihTrend]
```

where `SERVER.pid_astatus[07][0].F_CV.Value` is the name of the column

This fails as well with *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.*

```
SELECT * FROM 
    iHist...[SELECT [SERVER.pid_astatus[[07]][[0]].F_CV.Value] from ihTrend]`
```

Any ideas on how I can make SQL Server see this as a column?

**EDIT:**

Martins suggestion of the right brackets to escape the brackets work only on the outside of the sql call

```
SELECT [SERVER.pid_astatus[07]][0]].F_CV.Value] FROM iHist...[SELECT * FROM ihTrend]
```

However it does not work inside *Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.*

```
SELECT * FROM iHist...[SELECT [SERVER.pid_astatus[07]][0]].F_CV.Value] FROM ihTrend]
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT * FROM iHist...[SELECT [SERVER.pid_astatus[07]][0]].F_CV.Value]] FROM ihTrend]
```

I had to escape the column escape :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only need to escape these `]`

```
[pid_astatus[07]][0]].F_CV.Value]
```

This works for me

```
CREATE TABLE #t(
    [pid_astatus[07]][0]].F_CV.Value] int
) 

SELECT [pid_astatus[07]][0]].F_CV.Value]
FROM #t
```

Comment: If I test this with `declare @t table ([[[a]]] int) select [[a]]] from @t`, it gives an error.  Same for basically any other combination except `select [[[a]]]`

Comment: +1 Yeah, and `select * from syscolumns where id = OBJECT_ID(...)` confirms that my column name `[[[a]]]` is really named `[[a]`.  Good catch!

Comment: Martin thanks for the help so far, but as stated above it does not work within the main body of the []s.

Comment: @efbenson: Did you try the second part of my answer?  Your use of a subquery in the `table` part of `[server].[db].[schema].[table]` is kind of weird, I'm surprised it works with `select *` !

Comment: Do quoted identifiers work? "SERVER.pid_astatus[07][0].F_CV.Value". Ah Just seen Andomar's comment as well. I wasn't familiar enough with the linked server syntax to comment on that.

Comment: @Andomar unfortunaly the way that the linked server translates its data to RDBMS does not work with your second suggestion.  If it supported more features I am sure it would work.

Answer (score 4):

(Edited to reflect new knowledge, if you like this vote for Martin Smith's answer instead!)

Escape the `]` by doubling them:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    iHist...[SELECT [SERVER.pid_astatus[07]][0]].F_CV.Value] from ihTrend]
```

Based on your comment, try:

```
SELECT [SERVER.pid_astatus[07]][0]].F_CV.Value] FROM iHist...ihTrend
```

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.`

Seems to blow up the sql call to have that many brackets in there.  Different error though.  Normally the command `SELECT [SERVER.pid_astatus[07][0].F_CV.Value] from ihTrend`  in the brackets is all black with no syntax highlighting, but after I did what you suggested the syntax highlighting starts at the `from` to the end of the command