# column names with periods on a 2008 linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, linked-server

I'm using SQL Server 2005 and trying to select columns from a SQL Server 2008 linked server that have periods in them.

I've checked this post:

[Selecting a column with period in the column name SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284929/selecting-a-column-with-period-in-the-column-name-sql-server)

But I'm not getting the same error.

This is the code

```
    INSERT INTO [Linked_Server].Database.dbo.Table
           ([Column_Name], [Column.Name])
    SELECT 
           [Column_Name], [Column.Name] FROM local_table
```

I can select from the table locally, but when I try to select the same columns from the same table on the linked server, I get this error:

```
    Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
    Invalid column name 'Column.Name'.
```

EDIT: Fixed a typo with "[Column_Name)". This was a typo only in stackoverflow however.
**The typo is not the problem**

Comment: Your brackets (at least in your post here) probably contain a typo.

Comment: You are right. It is just in the post though. Still getting the problem.

Comment: I've got to ask... Are you sure that you've got a `[Column.Name]` Column in your `[Linked_Server].Database.dbo.Table`? As it's that line that's triggering your error.

Comment: Yes I am. I can select that column from the actual server, but not through a linked server. That's the reason for the post. I don't know why it would be inconsistent.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `[...]` with `"..."`? At least for the problematic name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a known issue with Linked Servers in SQL Server 2008. I had seen this page while I was researching, but I didn't see the workaround section at the bottom.

I ended up changing the query to use OPENQUERY instead, and now it works.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972856

Answer (score 3):

Replace ) on ] after Column_Name and try once again

```
INSERT INTO [Linked_Server].Database.dbo.Table
       ([Column_Name], [Column.Name])
SELECT [Column_Name], [Column.Name] FROM local_table
```

Comment: I typed it on my question wrong when changing the column names... Oops! This is the format of my actual query.

Comment: **This is not the answer to the question**, It only corrects my typo in the post.